# Can the doxygen output generated be made to look like msdn style documentation probably sandcastle generated?

Tags: c++, formatting, doxygen, msdn

I maintain a website that hosts documentation of our products. Most of the documentation follows msdn style.  One of the team uses doxygen to generate documentation for their C++ project. Now majority of our products uses msdn style and only this product uses doxygen is there anyway i can make the doxygen output style like msdn.

Comment: Please edit question and define "msdn style"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but as of my knowledge there is no tool for C++. For C# applications there is, as you already said, [Sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) which produces the exact output you are looking for, but the tool requires the XML-Documentation file generated by Visual Studio to build its MAML metadata. After that, there are XSLT transformations to that MAML to create the MSDN-style content.

Now, although it may be possible to generate the XML-Documentation file for C++ applications (with Visual Studio only), there still would be no XSLT transformations for C++ that could be applied. The best bet is to wait until someone creates a tool to create the XML data from any source code as well as said XSLT for C++. Or you can do all that yourself if you feel confident.

I love the documentation that Sandcastle creates, it is a real shame that C++ is not supported at the moment.